# Relation between eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T$ and $R$ to be real, square and symmetric matrices of the same size, which are not positive definite. Is there any relation between eigenvalues of $A$ and $T$ (or $R$)? Is there any specific name for $A$?
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
T& -R\\ 
R& T
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Thanks,

Comment: Note $A$ is not even symmetric. So the eigenvalues may not be all real. Whereas the eigenvalues of $T$ and $R$ are real. Therefore, even the interlacing property of eigenvalues cannot be applied. I don't think $A$ comes under some special category.

Comment: If for some nonzero vector $x$, $Tx=\lambda x$ and $Rx=\mathbf{0}$, then $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Similarly, if for $x\ne 0$, $Tx=\mathbf{0}$ and $Rx=\lambda x$, then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue  of $A$.